# How to loop through rows in R and impute the mean of the row for a specific index in the row?

Tags: r

So "temp" is a matrix. "unknown_position" is a list of lists that for each row in the matrix tells the position of which values to impute the mean of that row for. "Trainindex" simply is a list of row positions corresponding to rows in the temp matrix signifying that those rows are part of a training set:

```
apply(temp,1, FUN = function(i) ifelse(is.element(i, trainindex), NA,   (temp[i,unknown_position[[i]]]=mean(temp[i,]))))
```

Apparently, I get an error:   Error in unknown_position[[i]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: It will be easier to get help If you show some sample data for temp and unknown_position

Comment: @iuppiter I tried to answer your query according to my understanding of the problem. If this doesn't answer your question, you may ask for an improvement in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is in the application of `apply`.

When you define a function in `apply`, at any moment, it holds the element which is present inside the matrix. it **NEVER** holds the row number.

This is the main problem of the error.

You should try this:

```
lapply(seq(1,nrow(temp)), function(x){
    if (!is.element(x,trainindex)
        temp[x,unknown_position[[x]]] <<- mean(temp[x,]))
    else
        temp[x,] <<- NA

    return (NULL)
})
```

If the unknown positions contain NA, you may use `mean(temp[x,],na.rm=T)` instead.